# No puedo generar conexión con mi BD utilizando NodeJS y servidor MySQL mediante conexión SSH

Tags: mysql, nodejs, ssh, sequelize

Hace un momento que tengo este problema que me tiene un poco atrapado y en realidad estoy intentando entender, porque las conexiones SSH son algo nuevo para mi, ojalá puedan aportarme datos sobre este tema.

Tengo este problema de que al intentar hacer una conexión a la BD mediante un túnel SSH este lanza el siguiente error:

> Error: Access denied for user 'dev-user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> at Object.createConnection (C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Escritorio\Sistema de Reporteria - Metrics\api_metrics_puma_processing\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:253:31)
> at connection (C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Escritorio\Sistema de Reporteria - Metrics\api_metrics_puma_processing\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:60:38)
> at new Promise ()
> at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Escritorio\Sistema de Reporteria - Metrics\api_metrics_puma_processing\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:59:32)
> at ConnectionManager._connect (C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Escritorio\Sistema de Reporteria - Metrics\api_metrics_puma_processing\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:222:61)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Escritorio\Sistema de Reporteria - Metrics\api_metrics_puma_processing\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:174:32
> at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Escritorio\Sistema de Reporteria - Metrics\api_metrics_puma_processing\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:197:7)
> at async C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Escritorio\Sistema de Reporteria - Metrics\api_metrics_puma_processing\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:305:26 {  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
> errno: 1045,
> sqlState: '28000'
> }

**Cabe destacar que yo desde un cliente, del Workbench incluso en mi computador o ingresando desde el mismo SSH, no tengo problemas, así que mi contraseña está bien.**

Para dar más antecedente agrego mi código a continuación:

```
const SSH_USER = process.env.SSH_USER || 'admin'; // La conexión SSH todo OK.
const SSH_HOST = process.env.SSH_HOST || 'localhost';
const SSH_PASSWORD = process.env.SSH_PASSWORD || '';
const LOCAL_HOST = process.env.SSH_DB_HOST || 'localhost'; // localhost
const LOCAL_PORT = process.env.SSH_DB_PORT || 3306; // uso el default, 3306
const LOCAL_USER = process.env.SSH_DB_USER || 'root'; // USER: Uno que creé y le di permisos, además que creé uno para localhost y otro con el comodín %.
const LOCAL_PASSWORD = process.env.SSH_DB_PASSWORD || ''; // XXXXXX
const LOCAL_DATABASE = process.env.SSH_DB_DATABASE || '';

const conn = new Client();
const tunnel = async () => {
    conn.on('ready', async () => {
        console.log('// --------- Conexión establecida con el servidor. --------- //');
        const db = new Sequelize(
            LOCAL_DATABASE,
            LOCAL_USER,
            LOCAL_PASSWORD,
            {
                host: LOCAL_HOST,
                port: LOCAL_PORT,
                dialect: 'mysql',
                dialectModule: mysql2,
            },
        );
        try {
            await db.authenticate();
            console.log('Conexión exitosa a la base de datos.')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error al conectar la base de datos.')
        }

    }).connect({
        host: SSH_HOST,
        port: 22,
        username: SSH_USER,
        password: SSH_PASSWORD
    });
};

export default tunnel;
```

No puedo pillar el error. Espero me puedan ayudar, cualquier cosa estaré atento.

**¡MUCHAS GRACIAS de antemano!**

Comment: ¿Tú generaste en el servidor donde se encuentra la base de datos las dos claves, pública y privada, para la conexión vía SSH y autorizaste esas claves para el acceso? Una vez hecho eso, la clave privada debes descargarla en el equipo local desde el cual quieres conectar (en caso de que la BD esté en un servidor remoto). Y, debes también agregar esa clave al archivo de configuración, y darle permisos adecuados a ese archivo. Por favor, [revisa la documentación al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.3/en/mysql-shell-connection-ssh.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que debes tener en cuenta que pueden estar relacionadas o ser el problema directamente, te comparto alguna de las mas comunes:

- Host en la Configuración de la Base de Datos: Veo que estás usando
  'localhost' como tu LOCAL_HOST. Cuando te conectas a través de un
  túnel SSH, el host local (localhost) en el servidor SSH se refiere al
  servidor mismo, no a tu máquina local. Si la base de datos no está en
  el mismo servidor que el servidor SSH, necesitas proporcionar la
  dirección IP interna o el nombre del host del servidor de base de
  datos en lugar de localhost.
- Configuración de Sequelize: Verifica que las configuraciones de Sequelize estén correctas. En particular, asegúrate de que el dialectModule esté configurado correctamente y que esté apuntando a la biblioteca mysql2 como esperas.
- Errores de Conexión SSH: El mensaje de error indica un problema de
  acceso con el usuario dev-user@localhost. Esto podría ser un problema
  con los permisos del usuario en la base de datos MySQL. Asegúrate de
  que el usuario dev-user tenga los permisos adecuados para conectarse
  desde localhost.
- Permisos de Usuario en MySQL: Verifica si el usuario dev-user tiene
  permisos para acceder desde localhost. A veces, los usuarios de MySQL
  están configurados para acceder solo desde ciertas direcciones.

En caso de que estos puntos esten cubiertos, te aconsejo generar logs que puedan indicarnos a mas detalle el error preciso de comparto la documentacion de sequelize donde se aborda esta parte: [logs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/#logging)